# Redirecting homepage to root domain

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, domain, 301

How can I make it so the root of my domain is the default homepage in sharepoint with no redirects? Currently have a SP 2010 external site that is split into 2 seperate sub sites. Currently the root domain (e.g.www.google.com) 301 redirects to a 'Pages/default.aspx' page within the SP site.

This change has been recommended by an external SEO company to improve SEO equity...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2010 doesn't support friendly urls. SharePoint 2013 created the possibility of using friendly urls by mapping managed metadata hierarchies to url paths.

You can find more information here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn194311%28v=office.15%29.aspx

You might be able to do this on the IIS level:
http://blog.mastykarz.nl/friendly-urls-sharepoint-site-4-steps-iis7-url-rewrite-module/